# Create a VisualState if validation failed (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have Textbox inside a Usercontrol, I  want to create a visualstate, if validation for a TextBox failed. My code looks like this

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource ExtendeTextBoxStyle}" PlaceholderText="I'am Active"   HasError="{Binding IsInvalid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Height="80" Width="300"  x:Name="txtActive"  Text="{Binding TextValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" ></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind

```
  public EditTextControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = TV;
    }

    public bool HasError
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasErrorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasErrorProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is a dependency property that will indicate if there's an error. 
    /// This DP can be bound to a property of the VM.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HasError", typeof(bool), typeof(EditTextControl), new PropertyMetadata(false, HasErrorUpdated));


    // This method will update the Validation visual state which will be defined later in the Style
    private static void HasErrorUpdated(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EditTextControl textBox = d as EditTextControl;

        if (textBox != null)
        {
            if (textBox.HasError)
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(textBox, "InvalidState", false);
            else
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(textBox, "ValidState", false);
        }
    }
```

But this gives me a compile-time error

```
Unknown member 'HasError' on element 'TextBox'
```

What I am doing here, and how I can make sure that when validation for the textbox fails, my new `VisualState` get activated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBox` has no `HasError` property, so we can't set it directly, we need make `HasError` attach property and detect TextBox `TextChanged` event, then check the text is valid or not.

For your requirement, we suggest use [`TextBoxRegex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxregex) to approach. And use `XamlBehaviors` to invoke `VisualState` command.

For Example.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox
        Name="PhoneNumberValidator"
        extensions:TextBoxRegex.Regex="^\s*\+?\s*([0-9][\s-]*){9,}$"
        Background="Red"
        Header="Text box with Regex extension for phone number, validation occurs on TextChanged"
        >
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding (extensions:TextBoxRegex.IsValid), ElementName=PhoneNumberValidator}" Value="True">
                <Interactions:GoToStateAction StateName="BlueState" />
            </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
            <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding (extensions:TextBoxRegex.IsValid), ElementName=PhoneNumberValidator}" Value="False">
                <Interactions:GoToStateAction StateName="RedState" />
            </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveVisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="BlueState">

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="PhoneNumberValidator.Background" Value="Blue" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="RedState">

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="PhoneNumberValidator.Background" Value="Red" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</StackPanel>
```